# Regex - remove a specific character from a string except the first after number

Tags: javascript, regex

How to remove all commas from string except the first after number:

input: `",123,,,456,789,,,00,"`

output: `"123,45678900"`

I tryed this approach:

```
str.replace(/(.*,.*)(,)(.*)/g ,"$1$3");
```

but it isn't work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to go, I can't see a unique regex that does the job:

```
str.replace(/,?(\d+),/, "$1;").replace(/,/g, '').replace(/;/, ",");
```

Comment: You should try it first before posting.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to solve your problem or is it the regexp you're interested in? Your problem can be solved using

```
var tmp = input.split(",");
for(var i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
    if(tmp[i].match(/[0-9\.]+/)) {
        tmp[i] += ",";
        break;
    }
}
var output = tmp.join("");
```

Using only one regexp here is quite complicated, I *believe* (but haven't fully thought it through) that it can't be done without recursive patterns (which are not supported in Javascript): You'd have to replace arbitrary many instances of `/(.+?),/` with `\1` before and after the first `/[0-9]+,/`..

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly approach but should work fine:

```
',123,,,456,789,,,00,'.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function(a, b, i) {
    return a + (i === 1 ? ',' : '') + b;
});  // "123,45678900"
```